# Shell Scripting + SQLite3

Tags: shell, scripting, sqlite

Basically I need to find a few hundred *.DB3 files on three or four of our network shares and execute a SQLite3 script against all of them, extracting the outputs to a new DB3 file or even `CSV` file; but my shell scripting is very rusty and I would appreciate any help.

Using either Windows `CLI` or something that can be executed in `Cygwin`, how would I build a script to search up to three named shares (or mounted drive letters) for all files with a specific file extension (*.DB3) store these full paths and filenames in an array or file and then remove any duplicated file names.

For all files in this list, I then need to run a predefined SQLite3.exe script (example below) against all of these files and output this data into a new DB3 file or even a `CSV` file.

```
SELECT Product.Type AS 'Product', Product.Identifier AS SKU;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic footwork is to create a suitably formatted list of file names.  The following will create a file where the filename is in the first column, the full path in the second, tab delimited.

```
find /share/one /path/to/share/two \
    /export/third/share -type f -name '*.DB3' -printf '%f\t%p\n'
```

Pass that to `sort | awk` and create a simple script to print only unique names.  Does the order of the duplicates matter?  Perhaps you would like to check which duplicate is older, instead of blindly keeping only the first, or the last?  But here is a simple Awk script which does the former.

```
awk -F '\t' '!a[$1]++ { print $2 }'
```

To connect the pieces, run `find | sort | awk | xargs sqlite3 'your commands'`

If you need something a bit more involved, you can read the list of non-duplicate files in a loop:

```
find /share/one /path/to/share/two \
    /export/third/share -type f -name '*.DB3' -printf '%f\t%p\n' |
sort |
awk -F '\t' '!a[$1]++ { print $2 }' |
while read file; do
    sqlite3 "complex things with $file; more things; commit; done; etc"
done >output
```

Comment: The second part of the question is how to use the array to feed the sqlite3 executable and run the attach, query and detach commands for per database. Per database file these are:

attach "filename" as db1
go
SELECT  Product.Type AS 'Product',  Product.Identifier AS PartNo, GROUP BY Product.Identifier;
detach db1                        It is the output from the SELECT statment, for each database file, that I need then need to send to either another database to collect this information from all database, or alternatively a csv file would also work.

Comment: Not proficient enough with `sqlite3` to cover that part, and it wasn't very explicit in the original question; but updated the answer with another hint.